# Returning Row Count in a Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle-10g

I'm mostly  SQL Server person, so forgive me if this is too close to SQL Server, but in a nutshell using Oracle 10 I'm trying to build a procedure something like this:

```
PROCEDURE SP_INFO_EX_S(
    v_EX_ID    IN NUMBER,
    v_EX_ROWS               OUT NUMBER
    )
AS

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ExCount
FROM EXAMPLE
WHERE EX_ID = v_EX_ID
END SP_INFO_EX;
```

What I'd like this to do is return v_EX_ROWS as the total number of rows in the example table that match the WHERE Clause, but Google doesn't seem to have the answer to this.  Am I missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just put the result of the select into the out variable:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  into v_EX_ROWS
FROM EXAMPLE
WHERE EX_ID = v_EX_ID
```

You might be better of using a function though:

```
create or replace function SP_INFO_EX_S(v_EX_ID    IN NUMBER)
   return number
AS
  row_count number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      into row_count;
    FROM EXAMPLE
    WHERE EX_ID = v_EX_ID;

    return row_count;
END SP_INFO_EX;
/
```

Then just do:

```
select sp_info_ex_s(42) from dual;
```

Depending on your query tool, this might be easier to deal with than an out parameter.

Comment: In case you have too many rows, count(*) can be very slow, am I right?

Comment: @dezso - The count(*) may be able to use an index, regardless, a determination of very slow will depend on your definition of slow, too many rows, and what is acceptable.  Without these definitions a proper answer cannot be given to your question.

Comment: @LeighRiffel - [This question](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/22912-row-count-in-oracle/) states that counting 5 million rows would take 30 mins.  
On the other hand, I live part-time in a PostgreSQL world, and a plain `SELECT count(*) FROM table;` there involves a sequential scan.

Comment: @dezo - If you have a specific question, perhaps you should create a new question so we don't clutter the comments for this question.

Comment: @deszo: without any further details such a statement is completely meaningless. On my (outdated) dual-core desktop from 2004 counting 6 million rows takes less than 2 seconds. So who is right now?